# Issue in saving Special charcters in Oracle Database in BLOB datatype

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, apache-camel, solaris

While storing a report generated in CSV file from Java code using hibernate into the column which holds "**BLOB**" data-type in Oracle 11g makes all the special characters converted into **Question Mark(?)**.The character encoding for the Oracle DB is **WE8ISO8859P1**, the character set encoding for the database should be UTF-8 or AL32UTF-8 as far as I know to support all the UTF-8 characters. But since this is an existing application running in production I cannot modify the character set to UTF-8/AL32UTF-8 due to risk factor involved. I have been looking for some solution we may apply from the Java code during save option so that the character set is enforced.
I have tried below code

```
testReport.setTestReportBlob(new SerialBlob(byteArrayToStore));
```

Using Hibernate to store the save the reportBlob object,

```
getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(testReport);
```

While we extract the xl from blob data type , it shows special charcters as "?".

below is the piece of code where we are enforcing the character set before setting the byte array to be stored in database

`fileProcess.setFiledata(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.clas‌​s).getBytes());`

would setting following properties `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8 while getting the connection from the oracle database` will that help?Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance

PS: I am using toad for oracle as db client.

Comment: A blob doesn't involve the database character set at all. CLOB does. Where do you get the bytes from the text? Are you sure you are using the appropriate character set there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, below is the piece of code where we are enforcing the character set before setting the byte array to be stored in database `exchange.setProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME, "iso-8859-1");` `fileProcess.setFiledata(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).getBytes());`

Comment: You're calling getBytes() on a String, without specifying any encoding, thus relying on the default encoding of your platform. Specify StandardCharsets.UTF_8, and do the same when recreating the String from the bytes of the blob. Once again, the charset of the database is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, code should not be in comments. Please [edit] your question and add the information, properly formatted, in the question. I also don't see the `byteArrayToStore` anywhere in that code so I don't know how it connects with the code in the question. Its best to take some time and construct a [mcve].

Comment: Consider to use `NCLOB` instead of `BLOB`. In most cases **National Character Set** of databases are capable to handle Unicode.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: sorry for the format, I have edited the original post to make it bit clear, I am new to SOF, so pl bear with me

Comment: @JBNizet : while applying UTF-8 charset on getBytes(), it works fine for windows environment, but does not works for Solaris environment, is there any global charset that will work for all the environments , regardless of the environment whether it is LINUX/UNIX/SOLARIS or windows?

Comment: I don't understand why the environment would matter. UTF8 is a mandatory charset of the JVM on all platforms and supports any unicode character. And a blob is a blob is ablob: it contains bytes, and the environment is irrelevant here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @JBNizet - while executing the report in solaris environment, and doing a cat to the csv file show us the special characters intact, the same csv file when we download it to my local windows environment through winscp tool , and open the csv file can see the special characters converted to garbage value. Hope it make some sense.

Comment: Not really. If the file contains the right stuff, then it contains the right stuff. If this right stuff doesn't display correctly under windows, then your editor is to blame. That has absolutely nothing to do with the blob. It has to do with the editor, or with the usage of characters that are not supported by your editor.

Comment: @JBNizet  :  Thanks for your help, may be you are correct- may be editor issue  , I have now modified the code to
 `fileProcess.setFiledata(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.clas‌​s).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));`
and now I can see that the special characters are not getting converted to '?' , but when I open it in notepad++ ,it's showing proper special character, but when I directly open the csv file in Microsoft xcel it gives not ? but some weird characters something like `LÃ¶t` instead of `öt` . Why is this happening?

Comment: @JBNizet Also when I copy the content from notepad++ and paste it in excel file , special characters remains intact. I had to do formatting anyway by going to Data -> Text To Columns - > Delimited by comma.

Comment: As far as I remember, Excel will use your default platform encoding by default. If you encode the file using UTF8, then you need to add a BOM (google for it) at the beginning of the CSV file.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - Using NCLOB data type instead of BLOB has also helped but donot want to modify the database tables and wanted to check if there is any way I can do it via java code.Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet Added another column with datatype NCLOB and it is working in my local windows environment where spl characters are intact, I hope it works fine when the code is promoted to UAT/PROD which runs on Solaris.